# Declare method parameter to be interface with additional property

Tags: typescript

Within Typescript it is possible to inline declare a method parameter type with any properties:

```
function greeter(person: { firstName: string, lastName: string}) {
  return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

But is it also possible to let the type derive from an interface and add a property to it?

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName:  string;
}

function greeter(person: { Person, birthday: Date }) {
  // This is wrong but desired.
  ////return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " " + person.birthday;

  // Correct for the given signature but NOT desired would be
  return "Hello, " + person.Person.firstName + " " + person.Person.lastName + " " + person.birthday;
}
```

Unfortunately the above signature looks quite okay at first, but it tries to nest the Person interface under a property `Person`, which is not desired. The only approach I could find was to create a new interface that derives from the existing and use this instead:

```
interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName:  string;
}

interface PersonWithBirthday implements Person {
  birthday: Date
}

function greeter(person: PersonWithBirthday) {
  return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " " + person.birthday;
}
```

Another (not desired) approach would be to fall back to plain JavaScript and declare the incoming type as `any` or use another parameter for the function, but I'd like to have only one object parameter for my function that holds all properties:

```
// NOT desired: Use any
function greeter(person: any) { ... }

// NOT desired: Use second parameter
function greeter(person: Person, birthday: Date) { ... }
```

So my question is, is the only way to add an additional property to the given method parameter if it is an interface is to declare another interface with the additional property or exists another way like in the first example (that doesn't use an interface) to mix interface with additional properties in the method declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
function greeter(person: Person & {birthday: Date })...
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsjMFBmAHJwC2EAXMlVKAOYDcxpANnFVoNmLMGxBdiAX2LEYAVxAIwwHMnZQIESFAAUAB0w5m6SmoBk+AEYUwACwAmcAJ7MAInEhSAlPh7JNMHkoXAAiAAkIXl4sABpkUOQAamRDMxAAOnJKGnoUFMTElLTsTP5BPOSE6uKjTJsoeydnbiIZIlkiBBxsXggMmPZdDS0dXTxsiuFkAHIAKSwIGfjy3OmZt0Xl5Aaml2YQCAB3ZA9IXRmAJgAGAEZbgFp7p9uZ7x9vIA)